# What is the maximum number of screen sessions that can run simultaneously?

Tags: session, max, gnu-screen

On a Linux server I try to run up to 30 GNU screen sessions at the same time.
But some processes in some sessions keep to stop suddenly and at arbitrary time points without obvious error.

There seems to be a correlation between such events and the number of screens I try to run. So I wonder whether there is an upper limit for the number of screen sessions that can run at the same time for a specific user?

Comment: Looks like 40 is the default limit, but can be set when screen is compiled.

Comment: However, I came to the conclusion that the reason behind the arbitrarily closing screens was probably that the memory got used up and the system decided to kill some processes with high memory consumption. So it was not related to GNU screen after all.

Answer (score 1):

It might depend on the max allowed process numbers allowed to the user.

See `man limits.conf` and the result of the `ulimit -H -u` command